# Add and remove cell borders on edit

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, border, google-workspace

I am attempting to add and remove cell borders within a table in my sheet, depending on if a cell has data. The table populates with data once running another function in my script. The code that I constructed adds the borders however, if the cell returns empty is does not remove the borders. Also, it is adding additional rows of borders rather than a single row. For example if data is entered into cell C7, it will add an addition 6 rows after C7 (for range2 variable). How do I resolve this? I have provided my code below:

```
function onEdit() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Response Data');
const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Data Overview');
const sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName('Summarized Data'); 

var range1 = sheet2.getRange(1,1,sheet2.getLastRow(),10);
var range2 = sheet3.getRange(7,3,sheet3.getLastRow(),5); //.getLastRow method added for last row in table that generates 
var range3 = sheet3.getRange(7,9,sheet3.getLastRow(),5); //.getLastRow method added for last row in table that generates
var value1 = range1.getValues();
var value2 = range2.getValues();
var value3 = range3.getValues();

if (value1 === "") { range1.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);} 
else {range1.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);} 

if (value2 === "") { range2.setBorder(false, false, false, false);} 
else { range2.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);} 

if (value3 === "") { range3.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);} 
else { range3.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);} 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

I used an installable trigger. I don't think you need to.  I use it because it's easy to create for me.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  let sh = e.range.getSheet();
  let rg = sh.getDataRange();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart <= rg.getLastColumn() && e.range.rowStart > 1 ){
    e.source.toast('gate');
    if(!e.value){
      e.range.setBorder(false,false,false,false,false,false);
    } else {
      e.range.setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);
    }
  }
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Range.setBorder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal)